# Cassandra SimpleStatement protected constructor

Tags: scala, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I am using DataStax Java driver 3.0.0-alpha4 for cassandra with Scala. The following doesn't compile :

```
object Test {
 def get = {
   val stmt = new SimpleStatement("query")
   CassandraConnector.session.execute(stmt)
 }
}
```

The error I get is :

> Access to protected constructor SimpleStatement not permitted because
>   [error]  enclosing object Test in package cassandra is not a subclass of
>   [error]  class SimpleStatement in package core where target is defined

However using BoundStatement or PreparedStatement works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Issue solve in Java driver **3.0.0-rc1**, the public constructor is back

For earlier 3.0.0-x versions, use `session.newSimpleStatement(codecRegistry, protocolVersion)`